# Unknown error in someone else's code

Tags: bash

I am trying to install a program, and I keep getting this error message when trying to configure it:

```
/configure: 919: [: unexpected operator
```

I looked in the code, and this is what is located in that section of the configure file:

```
    if [ "$USENETCDFPAR" == "1" ] ; then
      echo "Using parallel NetCDF via NETCDFPAR option"
    fi
    echo " "
```

Looking online, I know something is wrong with that first line.  But none of the changes people have suggested fix it.  Anyone have any ideas?

Comment: What "shebang" does the configure script have? `==` isn't a POSIX supported comparison operator for the `[ ... ]` test construct - it's possible that the script was developed on a system where `/bin/sh` was a symbolic link to `bash`

Comment: #!/bin/sh
is the one listed on the top of the configure file

Comment: so try either changing `==` to `=` or changing `/bin/sh` to `/bin/bash`

Comment: So I'm not a coder or computer programmer or anything but "$USENETCDFPAR" is a string if I understand correctly.  IF that string has nothing no value assigned to it won't it break?

:echo $USENETCDFPAR
:(Nothing)

Comment: I don't see why it would break anything - it's perfectly valid to compare an empty string `""` against a non-empty string `"1"` (the result will be false of course)

Comment: Hmm, ill have to reach out to the author of the code and see what's up. Thanks for the advice @steeldriver.

Comment: Also, please report this issue to the author of the program you're trying to install. It's likely a bug, and they should be made aware of this so they can fix it.

Comment: @marcelm I will be doing that this morning.

Comment: If it's opensource, why not just tell us what it is?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The "unexpected operator" here is really `==`

In a POSIX shell, the test operator for string equality is `=`:

```
$ sh -c '[ "a" = "a" ] && echo equal'
equal
```

whereas

```
$ sh -c '[ "a" == "a" ] && echo equal'
sh: 1: [: a: unexpected operator
```

`==` is a provided as a synonym for `=` in the bash shell. From the `CONDITIONAL EXPRESSIONS` section of `man bash`:

```
   string1 == string2
   string1 = string2
          True if the strings are equal.  = should be used with  the  test
          command  for  POSIX conformance.
```

so probably the script's developer worked on a system whose `/bin/sh` was a symbolic link to `bash` whereas on Ubuntu it is a symbolic link to the POSIX compliant `dash` shell.

You can either replace `==` by `=` inside the `[ ... ]` test brackets, or change the script's shebang line to `#!/bin/bash`